How to render PGRaster with overviews?
I've imported testimp.tif into my PostGis database with raster2pgsql (overviews 2,4).
The raster tables I now have in my db are testimp, o_2_testimp and o_4_testimp.
This is how I add the raster in my MapContent:
    Style style = null;
    try {
        if(inLayer.equalsIgnoreCase("testimp")) {
            PGRasterFactory fac = new PGRasterFactory();
            PGRasterFormat r = fac.createFormat();
            String config = "<pgraster>" +
                "        <name>testimp</name>" +
                "        <database> \n" +
                "          <host>localhost</host>\n" +
                "          <port>5432</port>" +
                "          <name>aaa</name>" +
                "          <user>user</user>" +
                "          <passwd>pwd</passwd>" +
                "        </database>\n" +
                "        <raster>\n" +
                "          <table>testimp</table>" +
                "          <schema>public</schema>" +
                "          <column>rast</column>" +
                "        </raster>\n" +
                "        <time>" +
                "           <enabled>false</enabled>"  +
                "        </time>" +
                "      </pgraster>";

            File f = File.createTempFile("pgr", ".xml");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            fw.write(config);
            fw.close();
            PGRasterReader reader = r.getReader(f);
            RasterSymbolizer sym = sf.getDefaultRasterSymbolizer();
            style =  SLD.wrapSymbolizers(sym);
            Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader,style);
            rasterLayer.setTitle(reader.getGridCoverageNames()[0]);
            mapContent.addLayer(rasterLayer);
        }

The problem is that the raster is rendered twice in JMapFrame, once correct, and once as a little raster map (overview??) in the upper left corner of the raster map. See below.
How do I descide when to draw the different overviews? Now, it seems that all raster tables are allways rendered.


does it look ok in QGIS or other viewer?

It was the same in QGIS, could it be something with the parameters I use in raster2pgsql?

maybe, again I've never actually tried it
